# How to use leaflet in ionic 4 (Adding markers to the map)

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet

I am trying to use leaflet [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) in ionic.
I imported leaflet like this: `import leaflet from 'leaflet';`

To build the map I wrote this:

```
  loadmap() {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.map = new leaflet.Map('map').setView([this.lat, this.lng], this.zoomLevel);
  leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     // tslint:disable-next-line
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a '
  + 'href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a '
  + 'href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery '
  + '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(this.map);

}, 50);
```

}
This works just fine. The next thing I want to do is to add markers to the map like this: `leaflet.L.marker([this.lat, this.lng]).addTo(this.map).bindPopup('Hello!');`

This however does not work, I get the following error message

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'marker' of undefined

How can adress 'L', I have already tried some differnt ways, but with no sucess.
Any suggestions?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your import: `import L from 'leaflet'`

Then the rest of your code becomes like the documentation, i.e. `L.map()`, `L.tileLayer()`, `L.marker()`, etc.

Otherwise, if you keep your current import syntax, simply replace the `L` namespace from the documentation by your default import, i.e. "leaflet" in your case: `leaflet.map()`, `leaflet.tileLayer()`, `leaflet.marker()`, etc.